# og:type not recognised correctly when posting actions

Tags: facebook-opengraph

i keep getting this error when posting an activity to facebook:

Object at URL /states/karnataka/kempegowda-institue-of-medical-sciences/beijing-bites has og:type of 'website'. The property 'restaurant' requires an object of og:type 'og_collegekhana:restaurant'.

even though the linter reads it correctly. the url is http://www.collegekhana.com/states/karnataka/kempegowda-institue-of-medical-sciences/beijing-bites

what could be causing this? funnily enough i was getting this problem while adding sample actions as well earlier - and those used sample objects having just title, image and description.

Comment: this appears to be a facebook bug

Answer (score 0):

I see in the source of your example page that `og:type` is created twice. Remove that and see if the error persists.

Comment: Hi, it was working earlier - and I have seen others have the same complaint on fb, so I think it's a bug. I don't remember why anymore but I can't get rid of the second type param. It's a joomla site and the code is not optimum :(

Comment: Please post some code. It is tough to debug without seeing the code.